# jQuery Date Range Picker disable specific dates

Tags: jquery, date, range, picker

in example 26 of this page https://longbill.github.io/jquery-date-range-picker/ the author disables weekends. This function prevent also the selection of date range with invalid date inbetween. I am not interested in disabling weekends but only specific dates, which I would insert in an array. How can I do?
Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You'll need to provide more information. You might also take the [tour].

Comment: Put the 'specfic dates' into an array, and set their indices to -1 (non-selectable) before you show the datepicker. See sample code [here](https://webkul.com/blog/jquery-datepicker/). Please add what you have tried so far to your question in future

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, yesterday's post was confusing. I worked on the code, I uploaded it here http://layout999.hostinggratis.it/jquery-date-range-picker-master/

I have to act on the file http://layout999.hostinggratis.it/jquery-date-range-picker-master/demo.js

```
        beforeShowDay: function(t)
    {
        var valid = !(t.getDay() == 0 || t.getDay() == 6);  //disable saturday and sunday
        var _class = '';
        var _tooltip = valid ? '' : 'già prenotato';
        return [valid,_class,_tooltip];
    }
```

In the valid parameter of this function, Saturdays and Sundays are disabled. I should modify this parameter to make that not Saturdays and Sundays are disabled but specific days, contained in an array. I don't know how to do it, in javascript I'm a donkey.